# Connect to server within open source application

Tags: open-source, configuration, connection

What is the best, most secure way to connect to a server such as a mysql server, from within a program that's source code will be released? I'm trying to keep from just giving out an ip address. Sorry if this is a bad or simple question, I am really new to network centered programming.

Comment: The IP isn't what you want to worry about, it's the authentication credentials. The IP can always be sniffed client side regardless of whether or not the source is released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a file that holds that info and then the program just reads from there, or you can have that info in a source code file that you include in the main program. Just don't share them with the rest of the source code and you're set ;)

```
e.g.
readDataFromFile("confidential.dat")
or
#include "confidential.h"
(...)
```

Comment: How would the program compile and run if I don't distribute that file with the rest of the source? And if I do, what would keep someone from opening that file and seeing it?

Comment: Does the released version need to access the MYSQL server after it's installed, or do you just need it? You could run a check to see if the file is included, if not prompt for connection information, etc.

Comment: The application connects to the server every time it is run. It will then fetch data throughout the entire runtime.

Comment: Like CodeJoust said, just ask for the needed info in runtime and save it in a file for further reference..

Comment: But how will it ask without showing an address or info in the code. Once again sorry for not completely following.

Comment: So you want to distribute the source code of your program for people to compile it and connect to a/your server, is this accurate?

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to do, but I want to keep the server somewhat secure from people who would just open up the source files, locate the server, and spam it or change info from the database.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly what you're trying to do is impossible, you want people to be able to compile de program and connect to your server. Doing that, they can change whatever they want in the source code, compile it and do whatever nasty things they want to the server, even with credentials you'd be screwed because you'd have to give them to people so they could connect to the server... It's a deadlock!

Comment: So what have other people done in this situation where they need an open source program to connect to a server?

Comment: www.sourceforge.net might be a good place to start :)

Comment: Ok, I have been trying to find some programs that are mostly desktop base but still need to connect to servers. Somewhat difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You would do this the same way you would make pi into a rational number. You can't make an IP address in a distributed program a secret. 'netstat' if nothing else will reveal it as soon as the program makes a connection to your server.